# Git rebase visual studio vs source tree

Tags: git, visual-studio, rebase, atlassian-sourcetree

I have been doing `git pull rebase` through `Visual studio`, and after resolving a conflict I just need to click `Continue` and that's it. It does not ask for a commit or commit message.

But when I want to do `rebase` in `source tree`, after resolving conflicts and clicking `Continue Rebase` I get this error:

```
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
error: could not commit staged changes.
```

It asks me to commit code after conflict is resolved to be able to do `Continue Rebase`.

My question is why `Visual studio` is not asking for this commit and `Source tree` is. Is there anything else that `Visual Studio` does under the hood except for git rebase --continue in order to achieve this? Some additional command or parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SourceTree is using regular Git, while Visual Studio, depending on its version, is using libgit2 or, [more recently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/git-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019), its own Git installation (and GitHub integration)

So the configuration between the two Git could be different.

VS might be set to execute:

```
cmd /V /C "set "GIT_EDITOR=true" && git rebase --continue"
```

That will bypass the editor step asking to provide a message.
Using that same command in a [custom action](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/using-git-in-custom-actions-785323500.html) in SourceTree would achieve the same result.